# stackoverflow issue in hybris application

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

We are getting stackoverflow error sometimes. (not able to replicate in local system).

Below logs in error file:

```
error getting de.hybris.platform.jalo.user.UserGroup.members : null
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.599 | [mde.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloSystemException: error getting de.hybris.platform.jalo.user.UserGroup.members : null[HY-0]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.599 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.type.ReflectionAttributeAccess$AttributeMethod.invokeGetter(ReflectionAttributeAccess.java:770)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.599 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.type.ReflectionAttributeAccess.getValue(ReflectionAttributeAccess.java:925)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.599 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item.getAttribute(Item.java:1840)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.599 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.ItemModelConverter.readSingleAttribute(ItemModelConverter.java:1157)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.599 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.ItemAttributeProvider.getAttribute(ItemAttributeProvider.java:101)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.599 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl.loadUnlocalizedAttribute(ItemModelContextImpl.java:236)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.599 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl.getValue(ItemModelContextImpl.java:227)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.599 |     at de.hybris.platform.core.model.security.PrincipalGroupModel.getMembers(PrincipalGroupModel.java:148)

INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 | Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at java.lang.String.toUpperCase(String.java:2833)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FromClause.translateNested(FromClause.java:58)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedText$2.translate(ParsedText.java:269)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearchTools.replace(FlexibleSearchTools.java:310)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedText.translate(ParsedText.java:263)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FromClause.translate(FromClause.java:48)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedQuery.translate(ParsedQuery.java:401)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedQuery.getTranslatedQuery(ParsedQuery.java:181)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.QueryParser.translateQuery(QueryParser.java:229)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch.translate(FlexibleSearch.java:2007)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch.search(FlexibleSearch.java:1412)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.link.LinkManager.getLinkedItems(LinkManager.java:422)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.link.LinkManager.getLinkedItems(LinkManager.java:368)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.link.LinkManager.getLinkedItems(LinkManager.java:338)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.link.LinkManager.getLinkedItems(LinkManager.java:249)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.security.PrincipalGroup$1.compute(PrincipalGroup.java:85)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.cache.AbstractCacheUnit.privateGetNoLock(AbstractCacheUnit.java:302)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.cache.AbstractCacheUnit.privateGet(AbstractCacheUnit.java:275)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.cache.AbstractCacheUnit.get(AbstractCacheUnit.java:182)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloTypeCacheUnit.getCached(JaloTypeCacheUnit.java:86)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.security.PrincipalGroup.getMembers(PrincipalGroup.java:96)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.user.UserManager.loadAllAdminUserPKs(UserManager.java:1090)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.user.UserManager.isAdminNoCache(UserManager.java:1047)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.user.UserManager.isAdmin(UserManager.java:1018)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.user.User.isAdmin(User.java:1075)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch.getUserFilters(FlexibleSearch.java:1891)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch.getQueryFilters(FlexibleSearch.java:1047)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.typecache.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchTypeCacheProvider.getQueryFilters(DefaultFlexibleSearchTypeCacheProvider.java:185)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/15 13:28:51.600 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedType.createParsedSubtypesAndRestrictionClauses(ParsedType.java:187)
```

What can be the possible issue?

Comment: This issue is not getting replicated in lower envrionment. But sometimes application stops running in case of this issue

Comment: I would try on the community of SAP for this issue to find more specific users. (because there is only 586 followers of the tag here ;) how many still active)

Comment: any root cause so far?

Answer (score 0):

This error could appear due to a recursive call which is not terminated properly. Based on the stacktrace that you have posted, it is likely that somewhere in your code, you're calling the PrincipalGroupModel.getMembers in a recursive manner.

Comment: It is not replicating very often. If it is due to code (calling recursive), It wold have replicated always

Comment: Unless this is a really expensive process and this only fail if the available resources are just enough to perform correctly. Meaning this could fail if an other thread (process) use this limited resources leading to this "random" error.